# error: could not create '/usr/lib/python3.5': Operation not permitted

Tags: python, macos, thrift

I am trying to install thrift servr on my Mac OS X.

I have download thrift 0.10.0, then have used the configure command. Its output is as below :

```
thrift 0.10.0

Building Plugin Support ...... : no
Building C++ Library ......... : no
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no
Building Java Library ........ : no
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : yes
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : yes
Building PHP Library ......... : yes
```

I then used the `make` command.

Now when i run :`sudo make install`. 
Its giving me the error as below.

```
error: could not create '/usr/lib/python3.5': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to see if the -H option for sudo helps.

```
sudo -H  make install
```

Further coverage on this can be found at [this link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623025/what-does-sudo-h-do)

As your using OSX, have you considered using the [brew package manager](http://formulae.brew.sh/formula/thrift)?

Also check if you have used **configure** correct. There are [special notes](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/os_x) for OSX which differ from the standard [build from source](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource) notes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `--user` at the end of your command? I encountered this issue when installing some python libraries and using this fixed it.