# Why sudo -H needs an extra command?

Tags: bash, sudo

I found this related question [What does sudo -H do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623025/what-does-sudo-h-do)
that demonstrates the usage of -H with

`sudo -H bash -c 'echo $HOME $USER'`

But I don't understand is why is `bash` necessary, because the echo command can stand on its own, but running

`sudo -H echo $HOME $USER`

will display instead current user variables (and not root's).

So why is (in this case) bash needed for the commands ran as sudo arguments to take in the -H flag?

This is also true if one specifies another user, like `sudo -H -u anotheruser echo $HOME $USER`.

Comment: Put an `echo` in front of `sudo -H echo $HOME $USER ` and you'll understand. It's not `bash` that is required there, it's a way to evaluate `$HOME` by the command launched by `sudo`, not by the current shell.

Comment: So what kind of commands do this evaluation? Obviously echo does't do it, does it have to be commands that are able to create an interactive shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the command:

```
sudo -H echo $HOME $USER
```

the variables `$HOME` and `$USER` are evaluated by the current shell. They are replaced with their values and the command line adjusted this way is passed to `sudo`.

F.e. if your username is `foo` and your home is `/home/foo`, the command above is the same thing as:

```
sudo -H echo /home/foo foo
```

It's not necessarily `bash` that is required to get what you want. It's required a way to evaluate the environment variables by the command that is executed by `sudo`, not by the current shell.

When you run:

```
 sudo -H bash -c 'echo $HOME $USER'
```

the `$HOME` and `$USER` environment variables are not evaluated by the current shell, because they are enclosed in single quotes.

`sudo` receives the command line as it is written here (it's fourth argument is the string `echo $HOME $USER` as a single word). It then launches `bash` with two arguments: `-c` and the string mentioned above.

`bash` interprets `-c` as "execute a command" that is provided as the next argument. It then tries to run `echo $HOME $USER` (notice that the variables are not enclosed in quotes here) and, before running `echo` it replaces `$HOME` and `$USER` with their values (that belong to the new user now).

Running `bash` (or any other shell) is needed to do the variables expansion in the execution environment of the new user.

Answer (score 1):

`$HOME` and `$USER` are expanded by the shell before `sudo` even runs. You need `bash -c` to add a layer of indirection, so that the shell run *by* `sudo` does the expansion.