# How to set configuration for readline in Python

Tags: python, readline

According to the answer to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell), I installed readline for python to resolve backspace issue. If I logged in CentOS 7 as a root, I can backspace without any problems;however, if I logged in as a user, I have to run `pip install readline` to resolve backspace problem. I do not know where to set the readline so I do not need to reinstall it every time when I log in as a user. In my computer, it does not define "PYTHONSTARTUP" which is mentioned in one of solutions in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell). 
Any further help and suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duoicate of [how-do-i-install-a-pip-package-globally-instead-of-locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936212/how-do-i-install-a-pip-package-globally-instead-of-locally)

Comment: No. My case is different from the one you gave. I did test the solutions given in the website.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: My system is CentOS 7. Intel Python was installed. If you use different Python, please see corresponding websites.

After studying online, I installed anaconda2, and set ~/.bashrc:

```
module load anaconda/anaconda2
```

next, set ~/.pystartup  (refer [link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interactive.html))

> import atexit 
>   import os,sys  import readline  import rlcompleter
>   readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
>
> historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.pyhistory")
>
> def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
>       import readline
>       readline.write_history_file(historyPath)
>
> if os.path.exists(historyPath):
>       readline.read_history_file(historyPath)
>
> atexit.register(save_history) 
>   del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath

In addition, my system is CentOS 7. The cluster is using intel compiler and [Intel Python](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-distribution-for-python/topic/704018). Thus, if you are using Intel Python, please install [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#download)3(may 2);else, please refer [link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interactive.html).