# Installing a python package globally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a personal python project. My directory structure is something like this:

```
/MyApp
----/App
---------/__init__.py
---------/ext
---------/icons
---------/app.py
----/setup.py
```

The ext and icons folders have source code and png icons respectively. The app is a GUI built using PyQT5.
The setup file would be something like:

```py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="myapp",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

After packaging the project with sdist and bdist_wheel, I will upload it to the PyPI index.

I will run the following from any computer

```
pip3 install myapp
```

I want the app to open when I run the following from the terminal from any directory:

```
myapp
```

My operating system is Linux. How would I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936212/how-do-i-install-a-pip-package-globally-instead-of-locally