# "No Module Named Mouse" error though mouse is installed

Tags: python

my code is having an issue in which when i run the program it gives the error message :

ImportError: No module named 'mouse'

this happens even though the module is installed???

Code below:

```
import mouse
print(mouse.get_position())
```

Comment: How did you install the module, and how did you verify that it is in fact installed? Also, how are you running the code that's producing this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936212/how-do-i-install-a-pip-package-globally-instead-of-locally i think this will help

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy i installed the module through cmd using pip3 install mouse

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDE like PyCharm make sure you download the package on the IDE.

In pycharm go to **Setting**->**Python Interpretor**->**Click +** ->**search your package name (in this case mouse)** -> **install the package**

Comment: thanks this worked! though weirdly not when i used cmd for idle???

Comment: @PopSquip Happy to hear :)

Comment: @PopSquip i will glad if you can mark my answer that helped you

Comment: @PopSquip: then you have more than one Python installation or virtualenv and didn't set up your IDE to use the correct Python environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the module `globally`, please try to install it and use the module using a `virtual environment` as an example you can use `anaconda`.